# Convert date string to yyyy-dd-mm format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm unable to convert date format using Utilities service in Google Apps Script. Can you please help?

Actual Output from the spreadsheet is `Tue Aug 30 17:00:51 GMT+05:30 2022`

I tried to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format using the utility service, but the output I get is gibberish "2022-33-30"

Here is the code:

```
var dueDate = sheet.getRange('I:I').getValues();//get values from the column I which are dates in mm/dd/yyyy format.

dueDate = new Date();
dueD = Utilities.formatDate(dueDate, "GMT+05:30", "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Cant you just reformat the spreadsheet?  Please provide the code you are using as a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like the variable `dueDate` is an array, 2d array. If you want to get date from one of the cells you can try: `var dueD = Utilities.formatDate(dueDate[0][0], "GMT+05:30", "mm/dd/yyyy");` this way you will get date from first cell of the range

Comment: But actually show what you have and the desired output. A couple of screenshots. Probably all you need is to tweak cell formatting in the column.

Comment: Hi team, 

Thanks for looking into it & Apologies for the inconvenience caused; I'm just a beginner  

Here is the code which I've been working on. Having really a tough time   - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3QIfB60qlwimw8GMtHoi58TjPobvS2gHImKHIyur5Q/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate your help